# Firebird 3.0 embedded DB after new install of Windows 10 with new Username not accessible anymore

Tags: firebird, firedac, firebird-3.0, firebird-embedded

I coded a CRM application in Delphi some years ago and worked with it. Now I reinstalled my computer and the only thing that changed was the Username of Windows 10 itself. Result is, that I cannot access the Firebird 3.0 db anymore and I have no idea what the problem is or might be, because, as far as I know, the Firebird 3.0 Embedded librart does not perform authentication.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: If you have hardcoded the paths to your database files and it was stored at some user based folder that would mena that now your application can't find the database files as they are in different locations since username folder name changed.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Delphi, as it is only about not being able to access the DB and not Delphi code. I've removed the Delphi tag.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the error messages. If you want debugging tips or ideas, then Stack Overflow is probably the wrong place, because such questions are usually unfocussed. As SilverWarrior says, check your configuration for the database location, likely it is looking in a different location than you expect. Also try installing a full Firebird install, maybe you're missing some libraries expected by Firebird (e.g. the Visual C++ runtime). Consider asking on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support), or maybe a forum about Firebird and Delphi.

Comment: Try SysInternals Process Monitors to check, where the database file was looked for and whether it was opened successfully or not

Comment: If you have no idea what the problem can be - try to read error message that you get trying to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to inspect access to your DB. Starting with Firebird 3 there is a new more secure way to access databases.
If your application use "old-school" (Firebird 2.5 and earlier) connection way you should provide [legacy Authentication](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-compat-legacyauth.html)